# Get Bounding Box value from Chitra

Tags: python, image-processing

I'm resizing 1 sample image and its bounding box using Chitra. My code looked like this

```
box = test_bboxes
label = ['dog']
image = Chitra(test, box, label)
image.resize_image_with_bbox((200, 200))
image.image = image.image.convert('RGB')
plt.imshow(image.draw_boxes())
```

It has no problem, but when I want to print the size of its bounding boxes (after resizing) using Chitra

```
print(image.bounding_boxes)
```

An error occured, the error was `AttributeError: 'Chitra' object has no attribute 'bounding_boxes'`

I have read the documentation in [Chitra](https://chitra.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/api/image/chitra-class/), but not found the solution

Comment: Entering `help(image)` will give you a list of all functions/methods that can be called using `image`. What do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

image.bounding_boxes is currently not working, checking the present and existing modules in Chitra ,image.bboxes takes care of listing the scaled bounding box values.

> print(image.bboxes)

If you want to list (xmin,ymin,xmax,ymax) values separately

> print(image.bboxes[0].x1,image.bboxes[0].y1,image.bboxes[0].x2,image.bboxes[0].y2)

Above statement may list values in *float* for getting corresponding *int* values

> print(image.bboxes[0].x1_int)